# Html entities back to special characters with php

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I want to convert special characters to HTML entities, and then back to the original characters.

I have used `htmlentities()` and then `html_entity_decode()`. It worked fine for me, but `{` and `}` do not come back to the original characters, they remain `&#123;` and `&#125;`.

What can I do now?

My code looks like:

```
$custom_header = htmlentities($custom_header);
$custom_header = html_entity_decode($custom_header);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://codepad.org/EpUQzjrx Please provide a complete example that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: My $custom_header look like this
<p><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() &#123;
 $("#left_side_custom_image").click(function() &#123;
  alert("HELLO");
 &#125;);
&#125;);
</script></p>

Comment: So you're htmlentity-encoding a string that contains `&#123;` and when decoding it it returns to `&#123;`? That's... expected.

Comment: Please follow the link please http://codepad.org/EpUQzjrx and do me a favour. I want &#123; to '{' other wise my jquery code doesnt work.

Comment: It looks like it's the exact same string, see this paste which outputs a bin2hex of `'{}'`: http://codepad.org/IvdErNzg

Comment: Please look at this http://codepad.org/kWs4Q275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though nobody can replicate your problem, here's a direct way to solve it by a simple [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
$input = '<p><script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() &#123; $("#left_side_custom_image").click(function() &#123; alert("HELLO"); &#125;); &#125;); </script></p> ';
$output = str_replace( array( '&#123;', '&#125;'), array( '{', '}'), $input);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tr7HLv) (click the 'Source' link in the top right)

**Edit:** I see the problem now. If your input string is:

```
"&#123;hello}"
```

A call to `htmlentities` encodes the `&` into `&amp;`, which gives you the string

```
"&amp;#123;hello}"
```

The `&amp;` is then later decoded back into `&`, to output this:

```
"&#123;hello}"
```

The fix is to send the string through `html_entity_decode` again, which will properly decode your entities.

```
$custom_header = "&#123;hello}";
$custom_header = htmlentities($custom_header);

$custom_header = html_entity_decode($custom_header);
echo html_entity_decode( $custom_header); // Outputs {hello}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but if any other character contains later which this time is not? How can i write a full replace code of such this type of characters?

Comment: @user1044804 - I've edited my solution to add a fix for your most recent paste.